# startActivityForResult onActivityResult in a fragment "not called"

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I call :

```
private void openGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
            PICK_IMAGE);
}
```

not execute never this :

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

And I have also implemented this :

```
//  @Override
//  public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
//      
//  }
```

but still not working.

I have this structure **ActionBarAcitivy** - > **FragmentPagerAdapter** -> **Fragment** - > **Fragment** - > here  startActivityForResult "**Fragment**"

***Note this code extends "Fragment"***

**THIS POST NOT RESOLVE !**

> Note after experience :
>
> ***Not exist any form, I spend 3 days with this issue, and -1 fragments, I put all in a activity (actionbaractivity)***
>
> ***I will not bother to use many fragments,  What a programmer can't do is waste time discovering imaginary code.***

Comment: Did you override `onActivityResult()` in the activity too? That could be interfering with this, unless you call `super.onActivityResult()`.

Comment: I've seen this issue with Child Fragments, is that, by chance, what this fragment is?

Comment: Yes I have @override + super.onActivityResult, and not work

Comment: check the onActivityResult() of the fragment activity so you can debug...maybe it's going there being consumed...or if it's a dynamic fragment (not declared in the XML) it might be that the fragment isn't attached to the activity anymore when it returns...not sure, the lifecycle of this fragment has to be checked.

Comment: fragment activity ??????? I never talk about activity, I have "Fragment"  extends "Fragment" and need call onActivityResult()

Comment: I have this structure ActionBarAcitivy - > FragmentPagerAdapter -> Fragment - > Fragment - > here "Fragment" I try override ActionBarAcitivy with onActivityResult but not work

Answer (score 1):

This line is the problem:

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
        PICK_IMAGE);
```

Instead, you should call this method on the *fragment*, not on the *activity*. This allows the system to route the response back to the correct fragment. So simply replace it with this:

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
        PICK_IMAGE);
```

Link to docs for reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#startActivityFromFragment

Comment: @user3718720 have u added permission?

Comment: What permissions I need ? in my other "activity" Works well but in my "fragment" not work

Comment: Not exist any form, I spend 3 days with this issue, and -1 fragments, I put all in a activity (actionbaractivity)

Answer (score 1):

There are few key concepts to remember:

- **nested fragments can't handle the onActivityResult**, only first level fragments can (ie the fragments you directly add to activity), details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580075/onactivityresult-not-called-in-new-nested-fragment-api)
- you must use **fragment.startActivityForResult** to get back results in your onActivityResult. If you do activity.startActivityForResult you will never get the results in your fragment
- in your onActivityResult methods (all) **always call super.onActivityResult**