# onActivityResult not work in Fragment using FragmentTransaction

Tags: android

I have problem with FragmentTransaction. My project use FragmentTabhost and one of tabs is Profile tab.
When Profile tab was choice I load Profile fragment. then I press Edit button, replace to EditProfile.
**code in Profile.java**

```
public class Profile extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{
........
     public void onClick(View v) {
         EditProfile profile = new EditProfile(); 
         Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
         bundle.putString("Token", tokenId);
         FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         transaction.replace(R.id.container_framelayout, fragment);
         transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**In code EditProfile.java**

```
public class Editprofile extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{
.........
     public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
          intent.setType("image/*");
          startActivityForResult(intent,SELECT_PICTURE);
     }

     @Override
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(requestCode==SELECT_PICTURE && data!=null)
        {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            avatar.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }
    }
}
```

in EditProfile Fragment, I have one button and one ImageView avatar. when button was pressed, I want get picture of garlary to show at ImageView. This problem is when I load EditProfile from Profile tab was chosen it run well, but I transfer from Profile Fragment onActivityResult not run.

Can you help me?

Comment: onActivityresult of main activity in which fragment is called will recived the data..from there you have to pass the result to the desired fragment

Answer (score 0):

It seems this issue was fixed with Android Support Library 23.2+.

More details: [Info1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36239436/2996699) and [Info2](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/onactivityresult-nested-fragment-support-library-v23.2/en)

**The simple solution is to use Android Support Library revision** `23.2.1` **or above.**