# onActivityResult not call in the Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-tabhost, onactivityresult

The structure of the app is like this:

```
tabHost (in Activity) -> contains -> TabFragment(extend base container fragment)
```

**1. The code in Activity**:

```
tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator("",
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_home)),
                HomeFragment.class, null);
```

**2. The code in HomeFragment**
(Notice that HomeFragment is not the actual function but a container like this, and it extend BaseContainerFragment):

```
public class HomeFragment extends BaseContainerFragment {

    public Home homeFrag;
    private boolean mIsViewInited;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.container_fragment, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (!mIsViewInited) {
            mIsViewInited = true;
            initView();
        }
    }

    private void initView() {
        homeFrag = new Home();
        replaceFragment(homeFrag, false);
    }

}
```

**3. BaseContainerFragment**

```
public class BaseContainerFragment extends Fragment {

    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.replace(R.id.container_framelayout, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    public boolean popFragment() {
        boolean isPop = false;
        if (getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            isPop = true;
            getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
        return isPop;
    }

}
```

**4. In the Home (The actual content of the fragment)**

```
UploadType fragment = new UploadType();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("form_type", "request");
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    ((BaseContainerFragment)getParentFragment()).replaceFragment(fragment, true);
```

**5. And in the UploadType , I call the camera activity but onActivityResult is only return in the main activity.**

```
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d("test1", "result2");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

How can I trigger the onActivityResult at UploadType? Thanks for help.

Comment: Fragments don't handle onActivityResult, but the activity

Comment: try this startActivityFromFragment(YourFragment.this, intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

Comment: Thanks for helping. Then is there any way to call the fragment onActivityResult  function inside main? Since I have switch the fragment (from Home() to UploadTab() , how can I get that fragment ? thanks)

Comment: try UploadForm.this.startActivityFromFragment or getActivity().startActivityFromFragment  but both undefined?

Comment: @user782104: `onActivityResult` is define in Activity instead of in Fragment

Comment: startActivityForResult where you call in UploadType or your activity

Comment: did you try adding `super.onActivityResult()`?

Comment: Check this post [startActivityForResult() from a Fragment and finishing child Activity, doesn't call onActivityResult() in Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085729/startactivityforresult-from-a-fragment-and-finishing-child-activity-doesnt-c)

Comment: see accepted answer and discussion of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment

Comment: see accpeted answer and discussion of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment

Comment: see accepted answer and discussion of this [onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment][1]  


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment

Comment: Also make sure your hostActivity launch mode not set to singleTask or singleInstance http://stackoverflow.com/a/38760091/3496570

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The reason why this doesn't work is because you are calling `startActivityForResult()` from within a nested fragment. Android is smart enough to route the result back to an `Activity` and even a `Fragment`, but not to a nested `Fragment` hence why you don't get the callback.
(more information to why that doesn't work [here](http://blog.shamanland.com/2014/01/nested-fragments-for-result.html) or on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580075/onactivityresult-not-called-in-new-nested-fragment-api))

Now in order to make it work I suggest you manually route the callback to the `ChildFragment` (=`UploadType`) in the `ParentFragment` (=`BaseContainerFragment`):

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Fragment uploadType = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container_framelayout);

    if (uploadType != null) {
        uploadType.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-fix-nested-fragment-onactivityresult-issue/en

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I've done by adding following code in my `MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In your Activity Override onActivityForResult() like this

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Now in your fragment u can get the activity result inside this

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      Log.d("test1", "result2");
    }
```

Make sure when your are calling start ActivityForResult in your frragment it should be like this

```
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, should I put the onActivityResult inside the BaseContainerFragment / HomeFragment as well?

Comment: Put onActivityResult from  where you are calling startActivtyForResult

Comment: Thanks. one more question, what if more than one fragment has startActivityForResult?

Comment: Did the solution work?If yes then accept the answer.You ca filter the result based on the Requestcode ie in your case REQUEST_CAMERA

Comment: Thanks for your patience. yes and if my case has fragmentA call camera , and fragmentB call photo album , both need the onActivityResult , how can I keep two onActivityResult?

Comment: Put different request code for your different intents.Also close the answer

Comment: that means it call both onActivityResult function? and it didn't call the onActivityResult function in fragment . Sorry, is there any way to debug?

Answer (score 6):

### For NavHostFragment of Navigation Architecture Component

If you are using single activity and have fragments inside the `NavHostFragment`, there is an issue of `onActivityResult()` of the child fragment of `NavHostFragment` not getting called.

To fix this issue, you need to call the `onActivityResult()` of the child fragments manually from inside the `onActivityResult()` of the host activity. The host activity is the activity that hosts your `NavHostFragment`.

Here's the Kotlin code for `onActivityResult()` of your host activity:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.your_nav_host_fragment)
    val childFragments = navHostFragment?.childFragmentManager?.fragments
    childFragments?.forEach { it.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TabActivity->ActivityA->FragmentB, it's not work.

use a bad bad bad way:

ActivityA.java

```
public void onSelectSomething(){

    ...

    startActivityForResult(intent, 22222);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (mFragment != null) {
        mFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

FragmentB.java

```
if(getActivity() instanceof ActivityA) {
    ((RepairerListActivity)getActivity()).onSelectSomething();
} 


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 22222) {
        // do things
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Loop through all child fragments of the activity
    for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {

        // check if the current fragment is YourFragment
        if (fragment instanceof YourFragment ) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

    }
}
```