# startActivityForResult doesn't work in a Fragment while image upload from camera or gallery

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview, fragment, gallery

```
public class Profile extends Fragment implements Profile_frg{


imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                final Dialog d = new Dialog(mainActivity);
                d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                d.setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_dialog);
                d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);


                gallery = (ImageView) d.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                camera = (ImageView) d.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                cancel = (ImageView) d.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

                cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        d.dismiss();
                    }
                });


                gallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try {
                            Intent gintent = new Intent();
                            gintent.setType("image/*");
                            gintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(
                                    gintent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(mainActivity,
                                    e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
                        }

                        d.dismiss();
                    }

                });

                camera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        // define the file-name to save photo taken by Camera
                        // activity
                        String fileName = "new-photo-name.jpg";
                        // create parameters for Intent with filename
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
                        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,
                                "Image captured by camera");
                        // imageUri is the current activity attribute, define
                        // and save it for later usage (also in
                        // onSaveInstanceState)
                        imageUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(
                                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                values);
                        // create new Intent
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

                        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_Camera_IMAGE);

                        d.dismiss();
                    }

                });
                d.show();
            }
        });

}// Work Fine till here...



public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }//didn't detect this method
```

Comment: Have look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28577980/3117966)

Comment: Thanks.. but I already go through that link still I didn't understand that point... So help me out with any example If you have any..

Comment: Try implementing that or below answer :) It should work

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is no **onActivityResult()** callback in fragments.
You have to override activityResult method in your host activity(in which your fragment is defined)

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if(requestCode == GALLERY/CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
       Fragment yourFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT_TAG"); // same tag while adding fragment for the first time.
       if (yourFragment != null) {
           yourFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); //calling method that should be defined in your fragment.
       }
   }
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

And in your fragment do like this :

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data) {
   ...
   Pull your image data from data object
   do your further process from here.
   ...
}
```

Comment: thanks... Still not get the solution may be doing something wrong..  Actually in Fragment class I have to write my usual code in activity result ryte? and in main class I have to write

Comment: @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if(requestCode == GALLERY/CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
       Fragment yourFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT_TAG"); // same tag while adding fragment for the first time.
       if (yourFragment != null) {
           yourFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); //calling method that should be defined in your fragment.
       }
   }
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

Comment: Right. Are you still facing same problem ?

Comment: Yes! I'm facing same problem :(

Comment: Actually I'm using fragment with view pager..!

Comment: @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE/PICK_Camera_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  Profile yourFragment = (Profile) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Profile.FRAGMENT_TAG); // same tag while adding fragment for the first time.
         if (yourFragment != null) {
             yourFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); //calling method that should be defined in your fragment.
           
         }
     }
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }

Comment: Can you please share your host activity code and viewpager adapter code so that I will try to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **startActivityForResult** will not work directly if you are calling it from any fragment. After getting the result, the callback will hit the **onActivityResult of the Hosting Activity from where you have to manually redirect it to the respective fragment**.

Below is the sample code of the onActivityResult of your Activity. Please note that this only redirect the result to the respective fragment.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1001:
            Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG"); // TAG should be same as the one you entered while adding the fragment
            if (frag != null) {
                frag .onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```