# How I can override onactivityresult method on nested fragment?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I use fragment not this one, import android.app.Fragment

I use this one, import android.support.v4.app.Fragment

because I use it for viewpager

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            if(position == 0){
                return new FragmentOne();
            }else if(position == 1){
                return new FragmentTwo();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }
```

In that case, FragmentOne extends import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
so not error but FragmentTwo extends import android.app.Fragment so it occurs the error

So I have two question

1. If I use viewpager, Fragment must be extends import android.support.v4.app.Fragment?
2. If I must be extends import android.support.v4.app.Fragment, how I can use onactivityresult?

Comment: Refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496682/onactivityresult-not-call-in-the-fragment

Comment: @AnuragSingh I want In FragmentOne call the Activity by startActivityResult but FragmentOne cannot override method onactivityresult

Comment: Oops sorry I hide the method so I can't find it sorry

Answer (score 3):

You can only use one of both libraries in your app, if you want legacy support add the `support` library.

And to notify your fragment about activity result changes you can do it using  an interface.

In your Activity:

```
public interface ActivityResultListener {
    onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data);
}
```

And create two methods to `set` and `remove` the `ActivityResultListener`

```
public void setActivityResultListener(ActivityResultListener listener){
    // You need the listener (ActivityResultListener) variable in the Activity
    this.listener = listener;
}
public void removeActivityResultListener(){
    listener = null;
}
```

Then, notify your listener if exists when you receive the activity result.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(listener != null){
        listener.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Implement the interface in your Fragment:

```
public class WhateverFragment implements MyActivity.ActivityResultListener{
    // ....
}
```

This forces you to override the `onActivityResult` method. There you are going to receive the result when the Activity gets it, do what you want. Only one step left, set your `WhateverFragment` as listener on the `onAttach` and remove it on the `onDetach` methods.

`onAttach` method:

```
((MyActivity)getActivity()).setActivityResultListener(this);
```

`onDetach` method:

```
((MyActivity)getActivity()).removeActivityResultListener();
```

This has been write on the fly so there may be errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should only use support library's Fragment i.e.  android.support.v4.app.Fragment  for backward compatibility.

Since you are using Fragment Adapter which is a class available in Support library and deals only with android.support.v4.app.Fragment hence you must use support library's fragment.

You can work normally with `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` as you do with `android.app.fragment`. Support Library also has `onActivityResult` method and can be easily inherited.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: I also think that but not auto complete the method, and not override

Answer (score 0):

For 1st-
Use **android.support.v4.app.Fragment** if your app needs support for api level 15.
else if your min api level is 17 you can use **android.app.Fragment**

For 2nd-
In you Activity class-

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case <requestCode>:
               ((FragmentOne)pageAdapter.getItem(0)).onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST QUESTION**

*If I use viewpager, Fragment must be extends import android.support.v4.app.Fragment?*

**In order to use [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) or [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html).**

CASE 1 : If you are targeting the app for below 17 android api level then use support library. (Below 17 childFragmentManager is not available in android.app.Fragment)

CASE 2 : If you are targeting the app for 17 and above android api then use android.app.Fragment. (From api level 17 and above childFragmentManager is available android.app.Fragment)

**In order to use [PagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html)**

You can choose any, either support library or android.app.Fragment.

**SECOND QUESTION**

*If I must be extends import android.support.v4.app.Fragment, how I can use onactivityresult?*

Review this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16449850/1567907).