# Nested Fragment in FragmentTabHost can not onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

I create an application as below:
Main activity includes `FragmentTabHost` which includes two `ContainerFragments` which include two Fragments separately.

Now I `startActivityForResult` from `UserFragment`, but `onActivityResult` in `UserFragment` cannot be called! What's wrong? How to resolve?

The project in https://github.com/VictorS-Zhao/TabHostAndNestedFragment.

Thanks in advance!

**Supplement:**
This is a strange behavior, the 1st nested fragment Community Fragment's `onActivityResult` can be called every time, but the 2nd nested fragment User Fragment's cannot be called. When `startActivityForResult` from `UserFragment`, but the `onActivityResult` in `CommunityFragment` is called.

**Solution**:
Finally I found solution in [onActivityResult() not called in new nested fragment API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580075/onactivityresult-not-called-in-new-nested-fragment-api/20543245#20543245)
According to this answer, should override `onActivityResult` in `ContainerFragment`, and use `getParentFragment().startActivityForResult` in `UserFragment`. That's nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the UserFragment is your child fragment (a child of ContainerFragment), `onActivityResult` method does not execute once you return from your activity which has been started with 
`startActivityForResult`.

It was a bug in the support library, I came over similar situation a while ago and it still was not fixed. Honestly, I am not sure whether it is fixed at the moment, you have to find out.

Here is a solution describing how to handle that:

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-fix-nested-fragment-onactivityresult-issue/en

https://gist.github.com/artem-zinnatullin/6916740

Basically the easiest way to make onActivityResult method executed in the child fragment is to start the activity from Activity level `getActivity().startActivityForResult()` or Parent Fragment `getParentFragment().startActivityForResult()` and notifying manually every fragment belonging to the calling Activity about invoked Activity's result.

Alternatively you can use some open source:

https://github.com/nuuneoi/StatedFragment

Hope that helps somehow.

**Response to the Supplement:**

Just as stated above, `BaseContainerFragments` belong to MainActivity, for those fragments `onActivityResult` method is called normally.

The problem begins when a child fragment is added to a parent fragment. For the child fragments `onActivityResult` is not called and you have to handle it manually in the Activity or the ParentFragment.

See :

[onActivityResult() not called in new nested fragment API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580075/onactivityresult-not-called-in-new-nested-fragment-api)

[onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment)

Comment: Thank you, please check my supplement further, it's strange.

Comment: Thank you very much, I found solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580075/onactivityresult-not-called-in-new-nested-fragment-api/20543245#20543245