# onActivityResult() is not called when startActivityResult() is called from Child Fragment in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, onactivityresult

I have read through the related posts. In every quaestion I see that onActivityResult() of activity gets called at least..the problem is how to carry the result to the fragments or nested fragments. But issue I am facing is different.
I am implementing Settings page that will have tabs with TabLayout from new Design Support library. In my app I have a single Activity which holds other Fragments...so I added a SettingsTabFragment which has ViewPager and a FragmentPagerAdapter to it.This adapter holds fragments for each tab.
One of the tab is User Profile settings where user can add his profile pic. And I called startActivityResult() from child fragment with ACTION_PICK intent. I overriden the onActivityResult() in Activity, in parent fragment (that holds view pager) and in SettingsTabFragment too. But none of them get called when I chose the pic from gallery.

None of onActivityResult() get called when startActivityResult() called from:
- child fragment.
- parent fragment. I did this from child frag getParentFragment().startActivityResult() AND also from within the parent fragment itself which is attached to activity directly (not nested).
- called using activity from child fragment with getParentFragment().getActivity().startActivityResult().

None of them lead to call onActivityResult() of, at least, activity.

When I called startActivityResult() from fragment I made sure I called just startActivityResult()..not getActivity().startActivityResult().

I follwed [onActivityResult is not being called in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-not-being-called-in-fragment) and tried the github lib suggested in one of the answers but seems owner told it is not recommended now. Also it has got compilation errors.

Nay thoughts on it ?

Comment: This is a known limitation. Call `startActivityForResult()` on the `Activity`, or possibly on the parent fragment, and have the activity/parent fragment pass the results down to the child fragment.

Comment: I have done that using the callbacks. from child fragment callBackToActivity.launchImagePicker() but no result. I tried from parent fragment too but of no use.

Comment: i agree with @CommonsWare initially onActivityResult of the parent activity will be called. You need to override  the onActivityResult of both parent fragment and the parent activity

Comment: That is what the issue is : onActivityResult() of activity itself is not being called. If I get that I can somehow move that results to any other components.

Comment: I have the same issue did you find any solution for that??

Comment: This is my code in child fragment in view pager.. I used getParentFrag().getActivity().startActRes(). This made onActivityResult() of activity hit where I have super.onActivityResult() due to which onActivityResult() of parent fragment is hit where I passed the result to child fragment.
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI); getParentFragment().getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, BaseActivity.REQUEST_CODE_LOAD_IMAGE);

Answer (score 1):

In my case i was picking up the mobile number from the contact by using intent in my child fragment class i.e. one of tab of view pager.

**calling the parent fragment from MainActivity:**

// Home is my parent fragment which contains Tab Layout and View Pager. I am calling Home Fragment by specifying tag, i will use this tag later on.

```
Fragment fragment = new Home();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment, "MobileTag")
               .addToBackStack(null)
               .commit();
```

**In My child Fragment class:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
                           ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Now it will call the onActivityResult method of MainActivity class
**In Main Activity:**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

By Calling super in onActivityResult of MainActivity will make a call to Parent fragment's i.e. Home Fragment's onActivityResult method.

In Parent Fragment i.e. Home Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentByTag("MobileTag")
        .getChildFragmentManager()
        .getFragments()
        .get(0);
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

here I am getting the 0th Child of parent fragment e.g. In View Pager Adapter if Fragment are added like:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0 :return new ChildFragment0();
        case 1 : return new ChildFragment1();
        case 2 : return new ChildFragment2();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then

```
getFragmentManager()
   .findFragmentByTag("MobileTag")
   .getChildFragmentManager()
   .getFragments()
   .get(0); // will return ChildFragment0
```

After this Make a call to child fragment's onActivityResult method:

**And Finally In Child Fragment:**

```
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    String contactNumber = "";           
    Uri result = data.getData();
    // get the result here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's a [known Android bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=40537). Until this is solved a workaround can be used:

```
public class HackForResultFragment extends Fragment {

    private static Fragment _callingFragment;

    private Intent _intent;
    private int _requestCode;


    public static HackForResultFragment newInstance(int _requestCode, Intent _intent){

        HackForResultFragment fragment = new HackForResultFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(2);
        bundle.putInt("_requestCode", _requestCode);
        bundle.putParcelable("_intent", _intent);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    public HackForResultFragment() {
    }

    public void setCallingFragment(Fragment callingFragment){
        _callingFragment = callingFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        if (arguments == null) {
            //Error handling
            LogUtil.Error("arguments should have been passed to HackForResultFragment");
        }
        else {
            _requestCode = arguments.getInt("_requestCode");
            _intent = arguments.getParcelable("_intent");
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null) { //first time only
            startActivityForResult(_intent, _requestCode);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        if (_requestCode == requestCode) {

            if (_callingFragment != null) {
                _callingFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                _callingFragment = null;
            }
        }
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putBoolean("startActivityForResultAlreadyCalled",true);
    }
}
```

In your calling fragment override startActivityForResult:

```
@Override
public void startActivityForResult(final Intent _intent, final int _requestCode) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    HackForResultFragment f = HackForResultFragment.newInstance(_requestCode,_intent);
    f.setCallingFragment(this);
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(f, null).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug is now resolved in support library version 23.2.0, so the best way to solve this now is to upgrade the support library.

Source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40537#c40

Comment: But I think my previous answer has value too - some people may not want to upgrade their support library for various reasons

Comment: In that case, you can combine the answer which will be even more useful..I think so.

Answer (score 0):

if FragmentActivity contain fragment1, fragment1 contain fragment2. Android can only handle `fragment1.startActivityForResult`,`fragment2.startActivityForResult`will not working.

For more detail and solution, watch the this answer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38221069/3883506)