# onActivityResult not called. neither parent's nor nested fragment's

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I have a hierarchy like this in my android app.

- ProfileActivity

  - SettingTabFragment

    - ProfileContentFragment

From inside ProfileContentFragment I call another activity called ProfileVideoRecordingActivity using startActivityForResult()

Here is the code in ProfileContentFragment

```
Intent videoRecordIntent = new Intent(mActivity, ProfileVideoRecordingActivity.class);
                            startActivityForResult(videoRecordIntent, REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_VIDEO_PATH);
```

Here is how I return from ProfileVideoRecordingActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(VIDEO_PROFILE_PATH, renamedVideoFile.getAbsolutePath());
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

//Go back to calling Activity
finish();
```

Problem is neither ProfileActivity's nor ProfileContentFragment's onActivityResult() is called.

ProfileActivity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

SettingTabFragment

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

ProfileContentFragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_VIDEO_PATH){
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String profileVideoPath = data.getExtras().getString(ProfileVideoRecordingActivity.VIDEO_PROFILE_PATH);
            Log.d("DEBUG", profileVideoPath);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried solutions from stackoverflow where I need to call fragment's onActivityResult explicitly from activity but that didn't work.
Here is what I tried.

ProfileActivity inside onActivityResult()

```
List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if (fragments != null) {
        for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

SettingTabFragment inside onActivityResult()

```
List<Fragment> fragments = getChildFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if (fragments != null) {
        for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

Both of them didn't work. What can I do?

Comment: What is the `launchMode` for `ProfileVideoRecordingActivity`?

Comment: launchMode attribute isn't there in manifest for ProfileVideoRecordingActivity.

Comment: What is the numerical value of `REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_VIDEO_PATH`?

Comment: @MikeM. REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_VIDEO_PATH = 9573;

I used an arbitrary number

Comment: look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580075/onactivityresult-not-called-in-new-nested-fragment-api

Comment: Put logs before `if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_VIDEO_PATH)` in `onActivityResult` and check if its called. In `Activity` and `SettingTabFragment` too.

Comment: @ADM I already have logs in place. None of the methods are being called.

Comment: @MohdSaquib Tried both getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode); and getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode); Sadly none worked.

Comment: I case of nested Fragment the parent Fragment  `onActivityResult` should get called . Take a look at link provided by  Mohd Saquib. Also let us know where are you calling `setResult()` update your code in question .

Comment: @ADM That was the first solution I tried. In my case even the ProfileActivity's onActivityResult() is not being called.

Comment: Try to put a `super.onActivityResult` call first inside `ProfileContentFragment. onActivityResult` to see if it works

Comment: @TamHuynh I just checked. super.onActivityResult() is the first line inside ProfileContentFragment's onActivityResult() method.

Comment: Ok just to be sure because I don't see the `super` call on your code in the question. And 1 more question, do you happen to `finish` the activity after calling `startActivityForResult`. If no, then this code looks all good to me

Comment: @TamHuynh I call finish() method in ProfileVideoRecordingActivity after setResult(). Thats the only place I have called finish() in this scenario. I'll update the code to reflect super statement