# OnActivityResult not called when nested fragment is using replace instead of add with Don't Keep Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I created a simple App below with

MainActivity -> ContainerFragment -> MainFragment

The ContainerFragment uses `replace` to commit the MainFragment.

I turn ON doesn't keep Activity`

When MainFragment call `startActivityForResult`, and return from the activity, the `onActivityResult` is not called.

> This doesn't happen when
>
> - It is a single Fragment. (not nested)
> - `Don't Keep Activity` is OFF
> - When ContainerFragment uses `add` to commit the MainFragment.

To replicate the problem, download the code in the following github and run it. (Remember to turn on `Don't Keep Activity`). Click `Start Activity..`, and then click `End Activity` and expect a Toast (no Toast, shows that the `onActivityResult` in the fragment is not called)

https://github.com/elye/issue_android_onactivityresult_not_called

Apparently there was previously a reported nested Fragment can't get `onActivityResult` in the past as posted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36239436/3286489, but stated has been resolved in Android Support Library 23.2.1. But for my case, I tried on Android Support Library 28 (Android Pie). So this is still a valid issue I believe.

Share it here in case I am wrong, and there's some explanation to this out there.

In case workaround, there's one recommended in https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-fix-nested-fragment-onactivityresult-issue/en.

Another workaround as reported in
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20543245/3286489

Comment: are you expecting the fragment's `onActivityResult` being called or the activity's `onActivityResult` to being called?

Comment: The `onActivityResult` in the Fragment is not being called though expected. It is called in the Activity's `onActivityResult`, but doesn't have the matching `requestCode`.

Comment: if you want to have the right `resultCode` use `activity.startActivityForResult` in the fragment

Comment: No, we want the `onActivityResult` called in the triggering (nested) fragment (commit with `replace` operation). It works when `Don't Keep Activity` is OFF, but not when it is ON.

Comment: Discovered it is still a bug out there even in AndroidX https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130327691

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer from https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36926548, it solved the problem.

The reason is before the Fragment is created, we should check that `savedStateInstace` is null first.

In this case in the project of https://github.com/elye/issue_android_onactivityresult_not_called,

the `ContainerFragment` it should be

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    if (savedInstanceState == null)
        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, MainFragment()).commit()
}
```

And in `MainActivity`, it should be

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    if (savedInstanceState == null)
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, ContainerFragment()).commit()
}
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you! I spent a day debugging this issue.

This seems like really strange behavior.

Comment: Programming with Fragment is hard as usual. I have written various issue one could fall into in https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/7-common-mistakes-easily-made-with-android-fragment-6fc85c44e783?sk=708bebf4db63882915115700b0f1c9ae

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, that Fragment.onActivityResult() has not been called, when I tried to call from within a fragment:

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult()
```

instead of

```
this.startActivityForResult()
```